# los datos de $_session['nombre'] no llegan a las demás páginas

Tags: php, session, apache2

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto web de práctica con la típica configuración PHP, MySql y apache2.
**nota:** 
Durante la edición de ésta pregunta pude detectar y solucionar el error. Aún así, quiero formular la pregunta y dejar mi aportación a la comunidad, porque considero que nadie habla sobre este error con claridad.

**Un poco de contexto:**
Estoy trabajando el área de registro y login. 
Todo lo relacionado con el registro lo he completado y me funciona perfectamente.
Básicamente consiste en una primera página llamada `registro.php` que contiene el siguiente código:

```
<?php session_start();
/*
  *la funcion Session_start debe de estar arriba del todo en el documento,
  *para que sea lo primero que cargue en header y para que
  *las sesiones creadas en otros documentos, inicien aquí también.
*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<?php
    require_once ('fragmentosPHP/head.php');
?>
<body>
    <?php
        require_once('fragmentosPHP/header.php');
    ?>
    <main>
        <h1 class="tituloMain">Registro de nueva cuenta</h1>
        <div id="nuevoUsuario">
            <?php require_once ('fragmentosPHP/registrarUsuario/formularioRegistro.php'); ?>
        </div>
    </main>
    <?php
        require_once('fragmentosPHP/aside.php');
    ?>

    <?php
        require_once ('fragmentosPHP/footer.php');
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Dentro de `formularioRegistro.php` tengo el siguiente código:**

```
<?php
    /*Verifico primero si se han creado estas sesiones que vienen de datosNuevoUsuario.php*/
    require_once './phpScripts/funciones.php';
    if(isset($_SESSION['errores'])){
        $errores = $_SESSION['errores'];
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['datosErroneos'])) {
        $datosErroneos = $_SESSION['datosErroneos'];
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['errores']) || isset($_SESSION['datosErroneos'])){
        $mensajeAvisoId = 'avisoErrorServidor';/*esto es para asignar un nombre al id del
div contenedor y así poder ponerle estilos CSS*/
    }
?>

<form action="/fragmentosPHP/registrarUsuario/datosNuevoUsuario.php" method="POST" id=formRegistro>
    <label for="correo">correo</label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="correo" name="correo"
    value="<?php 
       if(isset($datosErroneos['correo'])){echo $datosErroneos['correo'];}
       /*Con esto consigo que no se borre lo que el usuario ha introducido*/
       ?>" 
    required/>
    <?php if(isset($errores['correo'])){echo mensajeAviso('errores', 'correo', $mensajeAvisoId);} 
/*con esto muestro los errores de validación. mensajeAviso() pide tres variables: 
la primera el nombre de la sesion, la segunda el nombre del campo del valor 
y la tercera el nombre del id para poder darle estilos CSS y me imprime un 
div con el mensaje de error*/?>

    
    <label for="usuario">Nombre público de usuario</label>
    <input type="text" minlength="4" maxlength="10" placeholder="Nick" name="usuario" 
    value="<?php if(isset($datosErroneos['usuario'])){echo $datosErroneos['usuario'];}?>" 
    required/>
    <?php if(isset($errores['usuario'])){echo mensajeAviso('errores', 'usuario', $mensajeAvisoId);} ?>

    <label for="pass">Nueva contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" minlength="4" maxlength="20" placeholder="create a password" name="pass"
    value="<?php if(isset($datosErroneos['pass'])){echo $datosErroneos['pass'];}?>" 
    required/>
    <?php if(isset($errores['pass'])){echo mensajeAviso('errores', 'pass', $mensajeAvisoId);} ?>

    <label for="repPass">Repita la nueva contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" minlength="4" maxlength="20" placeholder="repeat password" name="repPass" 
    value="<?php if(isset($datosErroneos['repPass'])){echo $datosErroneos['repPass'];}?>" 
    required/>
    <?php if(isset($errores['repPass'])){echo mensajeAviso('errores', 'repPass', $mensajeAvisoId);} ?>

    <input type="submit" value="Registrarse" id ="btnEnviarFormularioRegistro">
    
    <?php
        /*si existe la sesion de 'MySqlConexion' significa que los datos eran válidos 
y NO habían coincidencias (el usuario o correo no estaban ya en la base de datos)*/
        if(isset($_SESSION['MySqlConexion']) && 
        !isset($_SESSION['errores']) && 
        !isset ($_SESSION['MySqlConexion_error']) && 
        !isset($_SESSION['MySqlConexion_errorNick']) && 
        !isset($_SESSION['MySqlConexion_errorCorreo'])){
            $mensajeAvisoId = 'avisoServidor';/*cambio el nombre, para CSS.*/
            echo mensajeAviso('MySqlConexion', 'aviso', $mensajeAvisoId);
/*mostrará un aviso de confirmación: usuario registrado correctamente*/
        }
        elseif (isset($_SESSION['MySqlConexion_error'])) {
            echo mensajeAviso('MySqlConexion_error', 'aviso', $mensajeAvisoId);
        }
/*mostrará aviso de error*/
        elseif(isset($_SESSION['MySqlConexion_errorNick'])) {
            echo mensajeAviso('MySqlConexion_errorNick', 'aviso', $mensajeAvisoId);
        }
/*mostrará aviso de error*/
        elseif (isset($_SESSION['MySqlConexion_errorCorreo'])) {
            echo mensajeAviso('MySqlConexion_errorCorreo', 'aviso', $mensajeAvisoId);
        }
/*mostrará aviso de error*/
        session_destroy(); //Destruimos las sesiones para que al recargar, cerrar o volver a entrar,
        //no recuerde nada
    ?>
</form>
```

**Aquí es donde está todo el procesamiento de datos (`datosNuevoUsuario.php`):**

```
<?php
session_start(); /*He notado que esta funcion se necesita tanto aquí como en
registro.php para funcionar correctament no entiendo muy bien por qué la necesita aquí y no solo en la de registro.php*/

//recojemos los datos, saneamos y le asignamos variables si están seteados. Tres pasos en uno:
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $correo     = isset($_POST['correo'])  ? 
    strip_tags(trim($_POST['correo']))  : null;
    $usuario    = isset($_POST['usuario']) ? 
    strip_tags(trim($_POST['usuario'])) : null;
    $pass       = isset($_POST['pass'])    ? 
    strip_tags(trim($_POST['pass']))    : null;
    $repPass    = isset($_POST['repPass']) ? 
    strip_tags(trim($_POST['repPass'])) : null;
}
//con strip_tags quitamos tags de html 
//con Trim eliminamos cualquier indicación de espacios o saltos de linea (ACTUALIZABLE 
PARA FILTRAR MAS SIMBOLOS)

//creamos una variable tipo array para guardar ahí todos los mensajes de error que vayamos acumulando:
$error = array();

//VALIDACION de cada uno de los datos antes de utilizarlos en la base de datos:
    if (!is_null($correo) && filter_var($correo, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        /*en el caso de que el campo correo esté rellenado y tenga un formato válido
        lo convertiremos en minusculas:*/
        $correo = mb_convert_case($correo, MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8");
        //esto es para que de igual si ingresas el correo en mayusculas o minusculas
    } elseif(is_null($correo)){
        $error ['correo'] = '&#10060; El campo correo es obligatorio';
    } else{
        $error ['correo'] = '&#10060; El correo introducido es incorrecto';
    }

    if (!is_null($usuario) && is_string($usuario) 
        && strlen($usuario) >= 4 && strlen($usuario) <= 10
        && !preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_]/', $usuario))
        /*Significa que para cumplir la condición NO tiene que haber ningun caracter 
no-alfanumerico salvo el guion y barra baja*/
        {
    } elseif (is_null($usuario)){
        $error ['usuario'] = '&#10060; El campo usuario es obligatorio';
    } elseif(strlen($usuario) < 4 || strlen($usuario) > 10){
        $error ['usuario'] = '&#10060; El usuario debe tener entre 4 y 10 caracteres';
    } else{
        $error ['usuario'] = '&#10060; El usuario NO es válido. Use mayusculas, minusculas, 
        números, guiones o barras bajas.';
    }

    if (!is_null($pass) && is_string($pass) 
        && strlen($pass) >= 4 && strlen($pass) <= 20 
        && !preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_]/', $pass) && $usuario != $pass) {
    } elseif(is_null($pass)){
        $error ['pass'] = '&#10060; El campo contraseña es obligatorio.';
    } elseif(strlen($pass) < 4 || strlen($pass) > 20){
        $error ['pass'] = '&#10060; La contraseña debe tener entre 4 y 20 caracteres.';
    } elseif($usuario = $pass){
        $error ['pass'] = '&#10060; La contraseña NO puede ser igual al usuario.';
    } else{
        $error ['pass'] = '&#10060; La contraseña NO es válida, utilice sólo mayusculas, minusculas, 
        números, guiones o barras bajas.';
    }

    if (!is_null($repPass) && is_string($repPass) 
        && strlen($repPass) >= 4 && strlen($repPass) <= 20
        && !preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_]/', $repPass) && $repPass == $pass) {
    } elseif(is_null($repPass)) {
        $error ['repPass'] = '&#10060; El campo: repetir contraseña, es obligatorio';
    } elseif($repPass !== $pass){
        $error ['repPass'] = '&#10060; Las contraseñas NO coinciden';
    }

/*COMPROBAR COINCIDENCIAS EN BASE DE DATOS*/
if (count($error) == 0) { //esto solo se va a cumplir SI NO HAY errores:
    //Cargamos las funciones PHP y las funciones SQL:
    require_once('../../phpScripts/funciones.php');
    require_once('../../phpScripts/funcionesSQL.php');
    //Cargamos la información de la base de datos:
    require_once('../SQLinfo.php');
    //Reasignar variables para SQL (IMPORTANTE ANTES DE CARGAR LAS SENTENCIAS)
    $correo     =   mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $correo);
    $usuario    =   mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $usuario);
    $pass       =   mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $pass);
    $repPass    =   mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $repPass);
    //ciframos la contraseña de una vez:
    $hashPass   =   encriptar($pass);
    //Cargamos las sentencias:
    require_once('../sentenciasSQL.php');
    //Conectamos a la base de datos y Seteamos la codificación:
    formatearNamesBD($conexion, $formateoSQL);
    //Realizamos las consultas:
    //revisamos que no hayan usuarios con el mismo correo
    if(coincidenciasBD($conexion, $sentCorreos, 'correo',  $correo) === true){
        $_SESSION['MySqlConexion_errorCorreo'] = array(
            'aviso' => '&#10060; Este correo ya ha sido registrado');
            //creamos la sesion con los datos que metió el usuario para devolverlos:
            $_SESSION['datosErroneos'] = array(
                'correo'  => $correo,
                'usuario' => $usuario,
                'pass'    => $pass,
                'repPass' => $repPass);
        header('location: ../../registro.php');
    }
    //revisamos que no hayan usuarios con el mismo nombre en la BD:
    if(coincidenciasBD($conexion, $sentNicks, 'nick', $usuario) === true){
        $_SESSION['MySqlConexion_errorNick'] = array(
            'aviso'     => '&#10060; Este nick ya ha sido registrado');
        $_SESSION['datosErroneos'] = array(
            'correo'    => $correo,
            'usuario'   => $usuario,
            'pass'      => $pass, 
            'repPass'   => $repPass);
        header('location: ../../registro.php');
    }
    
    //Si no hay coincidencias ni en usuario ni en correo, procedemos a hacer el registro:
    if(coincidenciasBD($conexion, $sentNicks, 'nick', $usuario) === false 
    && coincidenciasBD($conexion, $sentCorreos, 'correo',  $correo) === false){
        
        //->acceder a la base de datos y registrar los valores en la misma:
        $registrarUsuario = 
        ejecutarSentenciaBD($conexion, $sentRegistrar, $hashPass, $usuario, $correo);
        
        /*Nos aseguramos que ha sido creado y creamos la sesión con el mensaje 
de confirmación y volvemos a pagina del formulario: */
        if($registrarUsuario){
            $_SESSION['MySqlConexion'] = array(
                'aviso' => 'usuario registrado correctamente');
            header('location: ../../registro.php');
        }else{
            $_SESSION['MySqlConexion_error'] = array(
                'aviso' => '&#10060; El usuario no se ha podido registrar. Inténtelo más tarde'
            );
            $_SESSION['datosErroneos'] = array(
                'correo'  => $correo,
                'usuario' => $usuario,
                'pass'    => $pass, 
                'repPass' => $repPass
            );
            header('location: ../../registro.php');
        }
        
    } 
} else {
    /*En el caso de que haya errores, creamos una var superglobal de tipo session 'errores' 
    para poder mostrar los mensajes de error.*/
    $_SESSION['errores'] = $error; 
     /*creamos una var superglobal de tipo session 'datosErroneos' para poder devolver todos 
     los datos introducidos al formulario mediante un array*/
    $_SESSION['datosErroneos'] = array(
        'correo'  => $correo,
        'usuario' => $usuario,
        'pass'    => $pass, 
        'repPass' => $repPass);
    header('Location: ../../registro.php'); //redireccionamos a la misma página para que no se salga.
}
?>
```

### El problema:

Con lo anterior terminado y funcionando correctamente, procedí a hacer el área de login.
El trabajo era similar, por lo que no había que cambiar demasiado el modelo de trabajo (un formulario de usuario y contraseña, validar, verificar, contrastar con base de datos y con ello generar las sesiones correspondientes). Mas sin embargo el código no funcionaba; sí lo hacía en estructura, al comprobar en la base de datos el usuario y la contraseña hasheada pero a la hora de redirigir al `login.php`, los datos de las sesiones desaparecían.

**`login.php` contenía el siguiente código:**

```
<?php
session_start();/* la funcion se hereda a todos los require/include aquí mencionados.
Session_start debe de estar arriba del todo en el documento.
*/
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<?php
    require_once ('fragmentosPHP/head.php');
?>
<body>
    <?php
        require_once('fragmentosPHP/header.php');
    ?>
    <main>
        <h2 class="tituloMain">Iniciar sesion</h2>
        <div id="nuevoUsuario">
            <?php require_once('fragmentosPHP/iniciarSesion/formularioLogin.php');?>
        </div>
    </main>
    <?php
        require_once('fragmentosPHP/aside.php');
    ?>

    <?php
        require_once ('fragmentosPHP/footer.php');
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Los datos del `formularioLogin.php`, se procesaban aquí: `datosLogin.php`**

```
<?php
    //RECIBIR LOS DATOS
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $usuario = isset($_POST['usuario'])  ?
        strip_tags(trim($_POST['usuario']))  : null;
        $pass    = isset($_POST['pass'])     ?
        strip_tags(trim($_POST['pass']))     : null;
    }
    //VALIDAR Y SANEAR DATOS
    $error = array(); //Array para acumular los mensajes de error
    
    if (isset($usuario) && is_string($usuario) 
    && strlen($usuario) >= 4 && strlen($usuario) <= 10
    && !preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_]/', $usuario)) {
    }elseif (strlen($usuario) >= 10 || strlen($usuario) <= 4) {
        $error ['usuario'] = '&#10060; El usuario debe tener entre 4 y 10 caracteres';
    }elseif(preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_]/', $usuario)){
        $error ['usuario'] = '&#10060; Existen caracteres inválidos en el usuario';
    }
    else {
        $error ['usuario'] = '&#10060; Por favor introduzca el nombre de usuario';
    }

    if (isset($pass) && is_string($pass) 
    && strlen($pass) >= 4 && strlen($pass) <= 10
    && !preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_]/', $pass)) {
    }elseif (strlen($pass) >= 10 || strlen($pass) <= 4) {
        $error ['pass'] = '&#10060; La contraseña debe tener entre 4 y 10 caracteres';
    }elseif(preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_]/', $pass)){
        $error ['pass'] = '&#10060; Existen caracteres inválidos en la contraseña';
    }
    else {
        $error ['pass'] = '&#10060; Por favor introduzca la contraseña';
    }

    if (count($error) == 0) {
        //Cargamos la información de la base de datos:
        require_once('../SQLinfo.php');
        //Cargamos las funciones PHP y las funciones SQL:
        require_once('../../phpScripts/funciones.php');
        require_once('../../phpScripts/funcionesSQL.php');
        //Reasignar variables para SQL
        $usuario =   mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $usuario);
        $pass    =   mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $pass);
        //Cargamos las sentencias:
        require_once('../sentenciasSQL.php');
        //Conectamos a la base de datos y Seteamos la codificación:
        formatearNamesBD($conexion, $formateoSQL);
        //COMPARAR CON LA BASE DE DATOS
        if(coincidenciasBD($conexion, $sentNicks, 'nick', $usuario) === true){
            $hashPass = ejecutarSentenciaConsultaBD($conexion, $sentExtraerHash, $usuario);
            
            if(validarPass($pass, $hashPass['pass']) === true){
            //Llegados a este punto hemos comprobado que Existe el usuario y que coincide con su hash
            //por lo tanto, extraemos todos los datos del usuario y creamos la sesión.
                $datosPerfilUsuario = ejecutarSentenciaConsultaBD($conexion, $sentExtraerPerfil, $usuario);
                $_SESSION['usuarioLogueado'] = array(
                    'usuario'   => $datosPerfilUsuario['nick'],
                    'correo'    => $datosPerfilUsuario['correo']
                );
                //var_dump($_SESSION['usuarioLogueado']);
                header('Location: ../../index.php');
            }else{
                $_SESSION['MySqlConexion_error'] = array(
                    'aviso'  => '&#10060; Contraseña Incorrecta, inténtelo de nuevo'
                );
                $_SESSION['datosErroneos'] = array(
                    'usuario' => $usuario
                );
                header('Location: ../../login.php'); 
            }
        }else{
            $_SESSION['MySqlConexion_error'] = array(
                'aviso'     => '&#10060; Este nick NO se encuentra registrado');
            $_SESSION['datosErroneos'] = array(
                'usuario'   => $usuario
            );
            header('Location: ../../login.php');
        }
    }
    //CREAR SESIONES EN CASO INCORRECTO
    else{
    //En el caso de que haya errores, creamos una var superglobal de tipo session 'errores' 
    //para poder mostrar los mensajes de error a modo de array.
    $_SESSION['errores'] = $error; 

    //creamos una var superglobal de tipo session 'datosErroneos' para poder devolver todos 
    //los datos introducidos al formulario mediante un array
    $_SESSION['datosErroneos'] = array(
        'usuario' => $usuario
    );   
    header('Location: ../../login.php');
    } 
?>
```

** y esto en `index.php`:**

```
<?php session_start();/* la funcion se hereda a todos los require/include aquí mencionados.
Session_start debe de estar arriba del todo en el documento.
*/

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<?php
    require_once ('fragmentosPHP/head.php');
?>
<body>
<?php
    
?>
    <?php
        require_once('fragmentosPHP/header.php');
    ?>
    <main>
        <section aria-label="Resumen del artículo">
            <h1>Título de la sección (primer h1 de la página)</h1>
            <p class="metaSection">fecha: autor: última modificacion: </p>
            <article>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt fuga nemo rem velit adipisci explicabo possimus a quas veniam beatae modi numquam ad quis suscipit laudantium fugit, vero, qui magnam.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt magni debitis ullam eius tempore natus blanditiis pariatur assumenda tempora adipisci!
                </p>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section aria-label="Resumen del artículo">
            <h1>Título de la sección 2</h1>
            <p class="metaSection">fecha: autor: ultima modificacion: </p>
            <article>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt fuga nemo rem velit adipisci explicabo possimus a quas veniam beatae modi numquam ad quis suscipit laudantium fugit, vero, qui magnam.</p>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section aria-label="Resumen del artículo">
            <h1>Título de la sección 3</h1>
            <p class="metaSection">fecha: autor: ultima modificacion: </p>
            <article>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt fuga nemo rem velit adipisci explicabo possimus a quas veniam beatae modi numquam ad quis suscipit laudantium fugit, vero, qui magnam.</p>
            </article>
        </section>
    </main>

    <?php
        require_once('fragmentosPHP/aside.php');
    ?>
    
    <?php
        require_once('fragmentosPHP/footer.php');
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Como podéis ver ambos contenían su `sesion_start();` correspondiente. pero login seguía sin funcionar.
Al introducir erroneamente un usario o su contraseña, no me generaban ningúm mensaje de error. Y si consultaba `var_dump($_SESSION['nombreDelaSesionEnCuestion'])` aparecían todos como NULL.

Answer (score 1):

### La solución:

Finalmente, revisando el código, me dí cuenta de la solución en `datosNuevoUsuario.php`, ya que durante mi práctica comenté lo siguiente en la primera línea:

```
session_start(); /*He notado que esta funcion se necesita tanto aquí como en
registro.php para funcionar correctamente no entiendo muy bien por qué la necesita aquí y no solo en la de registro.php*/
```

Según toda la documentación y manuales de PHP que leí, mencionaba la importancia de declarar session_start() al principio del documento en la **página de destino**  para poder "importar" todas las sessiones y sus datos creados. Pensar que funcionaba así fue el origen del error y la confusión.

Al incluir `session_start()` en `datosLogin.php`, funcionó todo correctamente, ya que allí no estaba declarado.

### En resumen:

Para entenderlo, he imaginado que funciona como un puente:
Mis datos salen de `datosNuevoUsuario.php` -y van hacia-> `formularioNuevoUsuario.php`
por lo tanto en ambos debo "abrir la entrada" con `session_start()`.
Igualmente para `datosLogin.php` --> `index.php`.